# Fill datatable from database in jpa

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces

```
public List<MemberEntity> getMember() {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("PrimeEclipseLink");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory
            .createEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("Select * FROM member");
    memberEntities = (List<MemberEntity>)query.getResultList();
    return memberEntities;

}
```

I want to fill  my databable from database.but it doesnt work please help me:) when I click list button the table fill like picture.by the way,my database contains 3 records.thats why 3 zero.
[image]

xhtml page is here.

```
<h:form id="member">

<p:dataTable var="members" value="#{mainScreen.memberEntities}">
<p:column headerText="name">
<h:outputText value="#{memberEntity.name}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="surname">
<h:outputText value="#{memberEntity.surname}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="fathername">
<h:outputText value="#{memberEntity.fathername}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="age">
<h:outputText value="#{memberEntity.age}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="email">
<h:outputText value="#{memberEntity.email}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="username">
<h:outputText value="#{memberEntity.username}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="password">
<h:outputText value="#{memberEntity.password}" />
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

` @ManagedBean

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class MemberEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int memberid;
private int age;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String fathername;
private String email;
private String username;
private String password;

public MemberEntity(int memberid, int age, String name, String surname,
        String fathername, String email, String username, String password) {
    super();
    this.memberid = memberid;
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.fathername = fathername;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public MemberEntity() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public int getMemberid() {
    return memberid;
}

public void setMemberid(int memberid) {
    this.memberid = memberid;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getFathername() {
    return fathername;
}

public void setFathername(String fathername) {
    this.fathername = fathername;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "Member [memberid=" + memberid + ",name=" + name + ",surname="
            + surname + ",age=" + age + ",email=" + email + ",fathername="
            + fathername + ",username=" + username + ",password="
            + password + "]";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. in **getMember()** method instead of createNativeQuery("Select * FROM member") true---> createNativeQuery("Select * FROM members,MemberEntity.class)

Answer (score 1):

In your `p:dataTable` the `var` attribute is named `membres`, while in the `p:column` values you are using `memberEntity`, so you have to change it to `members`.

From:

```
<p:column headerText="name">
    <h:outputText value="#{memberEntity.name}" />
</p:column>
```

To:

```
<p:column headerText="name">
    <h:outputText value="#{members.name}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: yes I tried to your advice before.but I get error numberformatexception

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: Tem 27, 2015 10:35:19 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
SEVERE: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"

Comment: please include the code of your memberEntity class to the question.

Comment: hmm can you edit your question and add the member entity?